# SwiftUI @Binding Misunderstanding

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use @Binding to update a value within a parent view. My code is not working as I would expect.

```
struct Trade: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    @Binding var bool: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Trade") {
            self.showSheet = true
            self.bool = false
        }
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

struct Profile: View {
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State var bool: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Trade(showSheet: $showSheet, bool: $bool)
                .sheet(isPresented:  $showSheet) {
                    Text("HELLO, WORLD.")
            }
        }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(bool ? Color.green : Color.red)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

The showSheet @State is being updated as I would expect. When tapped, the closure passed into the Button initializer will show the sheet however @bool is never updating. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you did not update it (ie. it is intilized with `false` and in button action assign `false` - no changes!)

```
Button("Trade") {
    self.showSheet = true
    self.bool = true      // << fix !!
}
```